# Ajax GET is working but not POST on the same piece of code

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

I am trying to find out why the same piece of code that I use is not working with POST method but it works completely fine with GET. Below is my code:

```
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="contact">
        <input id="name" name="name"/>
        <input name="email_address"/>
        <textarea name="message"/></textarea>
        <button id="submit"/>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>

        $( function(){
            $('#contact').submit( function(e){

              e.preventDefault();

              var userName= $("#name").val();
              console.log(userName);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  "submitContact.php",
                    data: {user : userName} ,
                    success: function( data ){
                        console.log( data );
                    }
                });

            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

And this is my PHP snippet( called submitContact.php) where I am trying to retrieve the userName from the Ajax request and just print it.

```
$name = $_POST["user"];

echo ("The name is : ".$name );
echo   ("   Method Used:").$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

However when I fill the form and the right data is sent to the server, the reponse I get back when I try to use the POST approach is that below.The strange thing is that with GET it works exactly as it was expected.

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: user in <b>C:\Users\Panagiotis\PhpstormProjects\test2\submitContact.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
The name is :    Method Used:POST
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: So, you tried the same thing using GET method first right? Or did you tried using POST first and it didn't work so you used GET?

Comment: try    data: 'user='+ userName ,

Comment: i tried, it should work

Comment: I tried by usiing POST first and then because it didn't work I changed to GET and it worked fine.Also guys I changed the ajax request to data: 'user='+ userName but still I get this error. However in both ways the request works fine as the data seems to go back to the server(I can see it in the firebug console) then the PHP doesn't get it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax code is fine, you just need to add a check before using PHP Super Global (`$_POST`) as:

```
if(count($_POST) > 0){
   $name = $_POST["user"];
   echo ("The name is : ".$name );
}
else{
   echo "Name not found";
}
```

you can also use `isset()` function, either `$_POST` set or not.

Comment: Change the code a little bit to:                                                          `if(count($_POST) > 0)
    {

        $name = $_POST['user'];

        echo("The name is : " . $name);
        echo ("   Method Used:") . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }

    {
        echo("Error no data passed");

    } `   And always the result moves to the second condition which is defined from else. So still is like the POST method doesn't procceed the results properly to the back.

Comment: @Panos: this is another thing, u r worried with else, than use else { // nothing}

Comment: or second solution is that, u can use isset() @Panos, my answer is related to undefined index....

Comment: Sorry, but in my previous comment I forgot to write the word "else" in the second part of the condition. I just wanted to focus on that the condition isset() or the (count($_POST) > 0) is not met initially. It is like when I use POST the data which is passed cannot be recognised.With GET both of your suggestions are working fine.

Comment: @Panos: yes my friend, that y i told u if u worried with else, than use else{//nothing} or default.

Comment: I see..The thing is that I don't want eventually to go for the else option but to gather the data sent by the ajax request. Something that doesn't happen at all as I get this undefined index error everytime with the POST.

Comment: @Panos: this is good, i have also updated my answer, now if answer resolved your issue than dont forget to mark as accepted, it will help to others who also facing this issue.

Comment: I am afraid I am not that clear to what I am posting..Sorry if you have misunderstood. The else is just another option that maybe I don't need to exist at all. Unfortunately your suggestion with either (count($_POST) > 0) or isset() is not working. This command $name = $_POST["user"]  is like never sets to the variable $name the desired value that comes from the ajax request.That's where the problem is.Thanks

Comment: @Panos: didnt got your points.... tell me r u not getting results in console.log( data );????

Comment: I don't get anything in my console.log. I just can see in the response section of the post query the error message which describes the undefined index. When I use the else condition of course I get to my console that "Name not found".But is better to talk without the existence of else condition.Only about that. `if(count($_POST) > 0){

    $name = $_POST["user"];
    echo ("The name is : ".$name );
}`   .The ouput is empty in my console.

Comment: @Panos: like $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  "submitContact.php",
                    data: {user : userName} , dataType: "html", 
                    success: function( data ){
                        console.log( data );
                    }
                });

Comment: I tried but nothing changed..Is it working for you?Maybe the answer is hidden on the server configuration somehow.

Comment: @Panos yes, its working for me... without datatype and also with datatype to.

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
 data: {user : userName}
```

To

```
 data: {'user' : userName}
```

Comment: I don't think that it's really necessary... is it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that makes any difference. I have started thinking if maybe my local MySQL server handles in a different way the POST from GET requess.But any relevant articles that I have read I couldn't find something relevant that refers to extra modifications needed instead of the default ones.

Comment: Yeah.I don't have anyhing extra.My HTML form ,the JQuery which sends to the server the proper data and my PHP script that handles the data received.